# GWT Client Server Communication (bootstrapping and so on,Gilead,Comet)

Tags: hibernate, gwt, client-server

I have designed a system using GWT, hibernate, PostgreSQL, comet and so on. Now I need to draw a diagram showing the architecture of the system. It works like this

1. Any browser,say firefox sends a request to the server
2. The server checks the request and see that the request is from a firefox browser
3. The Server chooses the appopriate javascript file and sends in the reply

Now in detail:
1. When the server gets the request from the client, it checks for which method in the remoteservice the client is requesting

1. The server thread execute this method
   During this request, the server may need to access the database through hibernate

Can someone help, I tried to present what's in my mind, in case there any error or if something can be add or improve, please help,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

At bootstrap time browser detection and appropriate JS loading is done by the `.nocache.html` file. The doc says:

```
The .nocache.js file contains JavaScript code that resolves the Deferred Binding 
configurations (such as browser detection, for instance) and then uses a lookup 
table generated by the GWT Compiler to locate one of the .cache.html files to use
```

Yes, GWT-RPC contains info on which method needs to be called. The server side of GWT-RPC then calls this method. The method then does it's work: calls the database, performs business logic, etc and returns some result. GWT then serializes the returned object and sends it back to client, where it's deserialized and turned into javascript object.

Comment: So, if i understand, first the client type the url, then javascript file from the server comes, examined the browser and sends a reply to the server informing the brower being used, is it that??

Comment: No everything happens on the client side. GWT does not inform the server about the browser type. http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#What's_with_all_the_cache/nocache_stuff_and_weird_filenames